# Connected hypergraphs

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

We say that a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) $H=(V,E)$ is *connected* if the following condition holds:

> for all $S\subseteq V$ with $\emptyset\neq S \neq V$ there is $e\in E$ that meets both $S$ and $V\setminus S$, i.e. $$S\cap e \neq \emptyset \neq (V\setminus S)\cap e.$$

Given $H=(V,E)$ connected, is there $E_0\subseteq E$ with the following properties?

1. $(V,E_0)$ is connected, and
2. whenever $E'\subseteq E_0$ with $E'\neq E_0$ then $(V,E')$ is no longer connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V=E=\omega$. Connected subgraphs are precisely those which contain as edges $n$ for arbitrarily large $n$. Clearly there is no minimal such subgraph.

Comment: Could you clarify on the edges? Is there only one edge, or every edge is an element of $ω$?

Comment: @Bullet51 $E=\omega=\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}=\{\{\},\{0\},\{0,1\},\dots\}$. That is, edges are the (proper) initial segments of $\omega$. Perhaps I went a little too far trying to make my answer as concise as possible :P